# Setting Image and Text to Button with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button with a drop down arrow to the right of the text programatically like so:

[image: Dropdown button]

The solutions I've seen have used title and image insets, but is there a way to set these with autoLayout programatically? Depending on the option selected, the text in the button could change and the text lengths will be different, so I'm not sure if title and edge insets are the way to go.

Comment: UIButton doesn’t use auto layout internally in a way that you can access. You could create a custom button-like view instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of where a `UIStackView` is placed in the main VC container view (in my case the `UIStackView` takes up all available space inside the VC). Basic user information is added in this case a telephone number.

I create a telephone number container view (`UIView`), a `UILabel` to contain the tel. no.  and an `UIImageView` for the drop down arrow.

```
let telNoContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
let telNoLabel: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    view.font = font
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
let telNoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.tintColor = ACTION_COLOR
    view.image = UIImage(named: "Chevron")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

In `setBasicInfoViews()` simply add the `telNoContainerView` to he `UIStackView`. Then the `UILabel` and the `UIImageView` are added to the contain view `telNoContainerView`. Afterward the constraints are added as needed. 
You will need to change the constraints to fit your UI design.

```
fileprivate func setBasicInfoViews(){
    infoStackView.addArrangedSubview(telNoContainerView)

    telNoContainerView.addSubview(telNoLabel)
    telNoContainerView.addSubview(telNoImageView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        telNoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        telNoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        telNoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        telNoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        ])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        telNoImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoLabel.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        telNoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
        telNoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
        telNoImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: telNoLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to set the image and title layout properties on a UIButton using AutoLayout.

If you want a fully custom layout for an Image and Title in a UIButton, I would suggest creating a `UIView` and add a `title` and an `image` as subviews using AutoLayout and then add a tap gesture recognizer to the UIView

```
buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction)))
```